# Restricting Textbox Input to Letters and Numbers

Tags: vb.net

I want to restrict a textbox to only allow letters and numbers to be entered. I have not been able to find anything online post 2014 and those all suggest keypress events. I'm not sure if something changed with VB since then, but I do not have keypress, keydown, or keyup. Is there a current method to do this or some way to enable keypress with modern VB?

Comment: One of the current methods _**is**_ using the `KeyPress` event (another is using a `Regex` in `TextChanged`). You cannot possibly _**not**_ have the `KeyPress` event... What technology are you using? WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET? (other)?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `MaskedTextbox`. You can set it's [`.Mask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx) property to only match alphanumeric characters.

But I'm assuming WinForms. If you don't have those keypress events I need to ask what you're actually using. Is it WinForms? WebForms? ASP.Net MVC? WPF? Xamarin?

An approach that will work across any of those toolkits is to let the user put whatever they want into the box, but only formally validate when they try to take an action (like submit a form or save a record). Then also include a visual validation check that immediately shows if their input will not be accepted. This is also usually considered better user experience.